# How do I get the children PID by a system call?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, process, kernel

I compiled and install a new version of the kernel and now I have to make the new kernel support two new primitives, I explain more below

I have this file, **mysystemcalls-test.c**  where I get the process and do forks in a **for** iteration. This is my test file.

```
//mysyscalls-test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <mysyscalls.h>

#define NCHILDREN 10

int main()
{

  int pids[NCHILDREN], i;
  int original_parent = getpid();

  printf ("before fork: current number of children: %ld\n", getnchildren(1));

  for (i=0; i<NCHILDREN; i++) {
    pids[i] = fork();

    if (pids[i] == 0) {
    while (getppid() == original_parent);
      exit(0);
    }
  }
printf("after fork: current number of children: %ld\n", getnchildren(1));

for(i=0; i<NCHILDREN; i++)
  printf("pids[%d]:%d\tgetcpid(%d,1):%ld\n" ,i,pids[i],i,getcpid(i,1));

return 0;
}
```

The real problem is in the second file, **mysyscalls.h** I can't make the right call for the child process.

```
//mysyscalls.h

long getnchildren (int debug){
  int children;
  children = pids[i];
  return children;
}


long getcpid (int order, int debug){
  int childrenid;
  childrenid = getpid();
  return childrenid;
}
```

I don't know how to call these pids in the mysyscalls.h file. I searched and tested some code that I found here but I don't have an exact answer for my problem. I wrote that code but isn't working, it return the same pid.

It's supposed that **long getnchildren** returns the number of child processes that the calling process has, at the moment the primitive is called.

**long getcpid** returns the pid of the child of the calling process, at position order in the list of its children.

Comment: Your `getcpid()` is always called from parent process, so it always gets the same pid from `getpid()`, why did you expect any other result? And how is it related to kernel?

Comment: Are you supposed to implement two new syscalls in the kernel?

Comment: What's the line `while (getppid() == original_parent);` for? You want the forking parent to exit and then have the child exit?

Comment: Also your `getnchildren` should return the number of children. It is returning the pid of some child instead. Also, how is that header file accessing `pids[i]` which is defined in the `.c` file?

Answer (score 2):

1. Get your own pid with `getpid`.
2. Iterate through all directories in `/proc` that start with a digit.
3. For each such directory, open the `status` file.
4. Read all the lines until you find the `PPid` line.
5. If the `PPid` matches the value from `getpid`, add this directory name to your array.

That will get you the IDs of every process whose parent process is this process.

Answer (score 0):

This outlines a simple way to do some common functions involving for PIDs. If I were you, I would circumvent trying to do this in C. More trouble than its worth, IMO.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# getting children generally resolves nicely at some point
get_child() {
    echo $(pgrep -laP $1 | awk '{print $1}')
}

# recursively getting parents isn't that useful, 
# so single use function
get_parent() {
    echo $(ps -o ppid= -p 36700)
}

get_children() {
    __RET=$(get_child $1)
    __CHILDREN=
    while [ -n "$__RET" ]; do
        __CHILDREN+="$__RET "
        __RET=$(get_child $__RET)
    done

    __CHILDREN=$(echo "${__CHILDREN}" | xargs | sort)

    echo "${__CHILDREN}"
}

get_children $1
```

```c
FILE *fp;
char path[1024];
char command[1024];
sprintf(command, "/bin/bash /get_pids.sh %d", getpid());

fp = popen(command, "r");
while (fgets(path, sizeof(path), fp) != NULL) {
    // children are listed here
    printf("%s", path);
}

pclose(fp);
```

I've been trying to cook up an unholy one-liner for David Schwartz's method, but I think it is a fully cursed solution. Some other bash-abuser can take a crack at it.